# Spamassassin can't start

Tags: debian, spamassassin, email-server

I have installed spamassassin (3.4.6-1) on Debian bullseye armel.
When I try to start it with sudo systemctl start spamassassin:

```
Job for spamassassin.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status spamassassin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The output of systemctl status spamassassin is:

```
    ● spamassassin.service - Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (final-sigterm) (Result: timeout)
    Process: 17612 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid $OPTIONS (code=killed, signal=TERM)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 855)
     Memory: 66.0M
        CPU: 1min 55.519s
     CGroup: /system.slice/spamassassin.service
             ├─17616 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir
             ├─17621 spamd child
             └─17622 spamd child

May 13 10:05:48 computer spamd[17612]: logger: removing stderr method
May 13 10:07:05 computer systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 13 10:07:09 computer spamd[17616]: spamd: server killed by SIGTERM, shutting down
May 13 10:07:09 computer spamd[17616]: replacetags: regexp compilation failed '(?i)(?:^|\s)(?:(?:[pP\xd1\xf1\xfe]|[\xce][\xa1]|[\xcf][\x81\xb7\xb8]|[\xd0][\x>
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783 (running version 3.4.6)
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: spamd: server pid: 17616
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 17621
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 17622
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: prefork: child states: IS
May 13 10:07:31 computer spamd[17616]: prefork: child states: II
```

The output of journalctl -xe is:

```
░░ The unit spamassassin.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
May 13 10:11:36 computer systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 17.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit spamassassin.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
May 13 10:11:36 computer systemd[1]: Stopped Perl-based spam filter using text analysis.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit spamassassin.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit spamassassin.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4819 and the job result is done.
May 13 10:11:36 computer systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Consumed 1min 55.652s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit spamassassin.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
May 13 10:11:36 computer systemd[1]: Starting Perl-based spam filter using text analysis...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit spamassassin.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit spamassassin.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4819.
May 13 10:11:50 computer spamd[17638]: logger: removing stderr method
May 13 10:12:27 computer kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:08:7a:4c:4a:ac:19:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0>
May 13 10:13:06 computer systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 13 10:13:09 computer spamd[17642]: spamd: server killed by SIGTERM, shutting down
May 13 10:13:09 computer spamd[17642]: replacetags: regexp compilation failed '(?i)(?:^|\s)(?:(?:[pP\xd1\xf1\xfe]|[\xce][\xa1]|[\xcf][\x81\xb7\xb8]|[\xd0][\x>
May 13 10:13:11 computer sudo[17623]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 13 10:13:18 computer sudo[17648]:    luigi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/luigi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
May 13 10:13:18 computer sudo[17648]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by luigi(uid=1000)
lines 4242-4280/4280 (END)
```

I have no idea what to do, but it seems to me that the problem is the "regexp compilation failed" error.
Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: Surprisingly there seems to be a process for spamd, although I still can't start or restart spamassassin.service:

```
    ps aux | grep spam
root      1219 29.5  4.7  26232 20988 ?        Ss   12:00   0:13 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir
root      1227 89.6  9.2  48684 41012 ?        Rs   12:01   0:26 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir
```

EIDT 2: "sudo spamd -D" works as expected. But I can't start spamassassin.service.

Comment: Have you tried "spamassassin --lint" to check the config?

Comment: Yes and no errors/output...   My problem with spamassassin occours too with defaults configs.

Comment: EDIT: Surprisingly there seems to be a process for spamd, although I still can't start or restart spamassassin.service.

Comment: Have you tried killing processes 1219 and 1227 and then restarting it with systemd?  also, have you looked at the logs for it.  (On my system I can get these with *grep "spamassassin" /var/log/mail.log | grep -v "postfix"*

Comment: Also, what is the output of *systemctl status spamassassin* ?

Comment: Yes, I can stop the processes with "sudo systemctl stop spamassassin". And "sudo spamd -D" works as expected. But I can't start spamassassin.service.

Comment: Same problem here, @tuxerri, have you ever found a solution? --lint gives a few lines I take as warnings, "unresolvable name" with the IP address of my DNS servers as name. 'sa-compile' succeeds. 2 instances of spamd running, but starting spamassassin service times out. In my case it started after upgrading from buster to bullseye, spamassassin worked under buster.

Comment: I just noticed '$OPTIONS' in the start command in status output, it's the same here. Shouldn't that have been expanded?
Also noticed that it never creates its /run/spamd.pid file, yet it is running as root, so it should have write access to /run.
For the rest it seems to work, it is just being restarted every 90 seconds.

Comment: Forget that remark about $OPTIONS, it is expanded in 'ps -aux' output.

Comment: Got it, YMMV, but in my case a stupid error in network configuration (dhcpcd, reconfigured from dhcp to static after the upgrade from buster to bullseye) was the culprit. I had separated my DNS servers by commas instead of spaces. Name resolution worked, but spamassassin didn't. Fixed it, and SA starts successfully.